# Auto update chrome extension not in web store

Tags: google-chrome

I am working on a private extension that I do now want to publish on the web store so I have specified an "update_url" in the manifest. Now the problem is that auto update is only working for extensions that are published on the web store.

Is there a way to keep it not published and be able to have an auto update for my extension ?

This is what I have done :

manifest.json:

```
"update_url": "https://localhost:44382/updates.xml"
```

updates.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<gupdate xmlns='http://www.google.com/update2/response' protocol='2.0'>
  <app appid='aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'>
    <updatecheck codebase='https://localhost:44382/extension.crx' version='2.0' />
  </app>
</gupdate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try including some code contained in the extension that will compare version numbers in the manifest and update from a git folder that has continuous integration set up.